# Create a star rating system using swt components in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Essentially I'm trying to create a star rating system.

I can create the components I need using a toolbar and toolitems as follows.

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(Composite, SWT.FLAT);

toolBar.layout();

ToolItem starButton1 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
starButton1.setImage("imgpath/img.png");
ToolItem starButton2 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
starButton2.setImage("imgpath/img.png");
ToolItem starButton3 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
starButton3.setImage("imgpath/img.png");
ToolItem starButton4 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
starButton4.setImage("imgpath/img.png");
ToolItem starButton5 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
starButton5.setImage("imgpath/img.png");
```

From here I can add listeners/etc.. to change the appearance of the stars if they are selected. However this doesn't use the behavior of a rating system (i.e. if you select the third star, the first two change to selected too).

I thought of trying to use a list, something along the lines of this that would give the stars some sort of ordering information:

```
List<ToolItem> stars = new LinkedList<ToolItem>();

stars.add(new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE).setImage("imgpath/img.png"));
etc...
```

So the problem here is that the set methods return void, keeping me from modifying the settings of the ToolItem object in the add

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm overcomplicating?

- Also I would like to avoid 3rd party libraries. I'm aware of this:
  [opal widgets](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/)

Comment: Erm, don't instantiate the `ToolItem` inside the add() parameter list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a star rating widget myself a while ago. Feel free to use it:

```
/**
 * The StarRaring is a widget that displays a predefined number of images side
 * by side to realize a "star ranking". This star ranking has listeners to
 * listen to the user input and adjust the number of stars painted with full
 * alpha. The remaining stars are painted with a user defined alpha value
 * (default: 150)
 * 
 * @author Sebastian Raubach
 * 
 */

public class StarRating extends Composite
{
    private Image image;
    private int hoverSelected = 0;
    private int selected = 0;
    private int nrOfImages = 5;
    private int alpha = 150;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean vertical = false;

    /**
     * <p>
     * Creates a star rating widget with a default selection of 1 star
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param parent
     *            the hosting composite
     * @param style
     *            the widget style
     */
    public StarRating(Composite parent, int style)
    {
        super(parent, style);

        /* Add dispose listener for the image */
        addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                if(image != null)
                    image.dispose();
            }
        });

        /* Add custom paint listener that paints the stars */
        addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e)
            {
                paintControl(e);
            }
        });

        /*
         * Keep track of the mouse movements and highlight possible new
         * selection
         */
        addListener(SWT.MouseMove, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                int x = arg0.x;
                int y = arg0.y;

                /* Determine direction */
                int step = (vertical ? height : width) + 1;
                int location = vertical ? y : x;

                /* Determine current index */
                int current = (location / step);

                /* Redraw if necessary */
                if (current != hoverSelected)
                {
                    hoverSelected = current;
                    redraw();
                }
            }
        });

        /* On mouse exit, reset selection */
        addListener(SWT.MouseExit, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                hoverSelected = selected;
                redraw();
            }
        });

        /* On mouse up, set new selection based on hover selection */
        addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                selected = hoverSelected;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Draws the images. Selected images are drawn with full alpha, unselected
     * images with the user defined alpha value
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param event
     *            The source event
     */
    private void paintControl(Event event)
    {
        GC gc = event.gc;

        if (image != null)
        {
            int stepX = vertical ? 0 : width + 1;
            int stepY = vertical ? height + 1 : 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < nrOfImages; i++)
            {
                if (i == hoverSelected + 1)
                    gc.setAlpha(alpha);

                gc.drawImage(image, 1 + stepX * i, 1 + stepY * i);
            }

            /* Reset alpha value */
            gc.setAlpha(255);
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Returns the image used for the star painting
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return the image used for the star painting
     */
    public Image getImage()
    {
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Set the image used for the star painting
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param image
     *            the image used for the star painting
     */
    public void setImage(Image image)
    {
        this.image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), image, SWT.IMAGE_COPY);
        width = image.getBounds().width;
        height = image.getBounds().height;
        redraw();
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Set the number of stars to be shown on the star rating
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Minimum = 1, Maximum = unrestricted
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param nrOfStars
     *            the number of stars to be shown on the star rating
     */
    public void setNrOfStars(int nrOfStars)
    {
        if (nrOfStars < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for number of stars. Minimum: 1, Selection: " + nrOfStars);
        else
            nrOfImages = nrOfStars;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Returns the number of stars to be shown on the star rating
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return the number of stars to be shown on the star rating
     */
    public int getNrOfStars()
    {
        return nrOfImages;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Get the number of selected stars of the star rating
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return the number of selected stars of the star rating
     */
    public int getSelection()
    {
        return selected + 1;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Set the number of selected stars of the star rating
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Minimum = 1, Maximum = nr. of stars available
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param selection
     *            the number of selected stars of the star rating
     */
    public void setSelection(int selection)
    {
        if (selection < 0 || selection > nrOfImages)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for star selection. Minimum: 0, Maximum: " + nrOfImages + ", Selection: " + selection);
        else
            selected = selection - 1;

        hoverSelected = selected;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Set the alpha value used for painting the non-selected stars
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Minimum = 0, Maximum = 255
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param alpha
     *            The alpha value used for painting the non-selected stars
     */
    public void setAlpha(int alpha)
    {

        if (alpha < 0 || alpha > 255)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid alpha value. Minimum: 0, Maximum: 255, Selection: " + alpha);
        else
            this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Returns the alpha value used for painting the non-selected stars
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return the alpha value used for painting the non-selected stars
     */
    public int getAlpha()
    {
        return alpha;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Set the orientation of the widget to vertical
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param vertical
     *            Set to true if the stars should be aligned in a vertical and
     *            to false if the stars should be aligned in a horizontal line
     */
    public void setVertical(boolean vertical)
    {
        this.vertical = vertical;
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Returns the orientation of the widget
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return true, if the widget is vertical, false if the widget is
     *         horizontal
     */
    public boolean getVertical()
    {
        return vertical;
    }

    @Override
    public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed)
    {
        int overallWidth = 0;
        int overallHeight = 0;

        /* Determine the preferred dimensions of the widget */
        if (image != null)
        {
            overallWidth = vertical ? width : width * nrOfImages + nrOfImages - 1;
            overallHeight = vertical ? height * nrOfImages + nrOfImages - 1 : height;
        }

        /* Consider hints */
        if (wHint != SWT.DEFAULT && wHint < overallWidth)
            overallWidth = wHint;

        if (hHint != SWT.DEFAULT && hHint < overallHeight)
            overallHeight = hHint;

        /* Return computed dimensions plus border */
        return new Point(overallWidth + 2, overallHeight + 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        StarRating star = new StarRating(shell, SWT.NONE);
        star.setImage(new Image(display, "star.png"));
        star.setVertical(true);
        star.setNrOfStars(10);
        star.setSelection(3);
        star.setAlpha(100);
        star.setVertical(false);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: May I ask how to implement decimal star rating with your star rating widget ?

Comment: @star you'd need to paint the stars rather than using images and then determine how many and which fractions to draw based on the value.